# Configure Mercurial for SSH on alternate port and specific key with a passphrase?

Tags: ssh, mercurial, sshd

I'm trying to configure mercurial for use on a remote machine that has **sshd** running on an alternate port, and for which my login requires a particular key, which uses a passphrase.
**ssh** is configured and working fine, as with:

```
 ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa-xyz -p 1234 myuser@barney.example.com
```

My issue is what goes into the **hgrc** files to make this work with either of an alias (`barney-stuff`) or the **default-push** property:

```
 hg push barney-alias
 hg push
```

Most of the **ssh** documentation I've seen for Mercurial presumes the default port and a pre-loaded key.

I tried adding this to the repository's **hgrc** file:

```
 ssh = /usr/bin/ssh -i /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa-xyz -p 1234
 default = ssh://myuser@barney.example.com//hgroot/project1
```

But an **hg push** just hangs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My bad - the **hgrc** file should have the sections headers:

```
 [ui]
 ssh = /usr/bin/ssh -i /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa-xyz -p 1234
 [paths]
 default = ssh://myuser@barney.example.com//hgroot/project1
```

With that change, it gives me the error:

```
remote: abort: requirement 'fncache' not supported!
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

Which is because the remote machine only has a pre-1.1 version of Mercurial.